# Limit recycler view to a particular number of child views and load when scrolled to bottom

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have nearly 100-120 data stored in my sqlite db(android). 
I have done extracting the data to recycler view and showed up in a layout but how can i make the recycler view to load only 20 nos of data from the database and when the page is scrolled to bottom it again fetches the next 20 items and append it with the 20 item and show 40 items, till all the data loading gets completed.

**Here is my Code.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recycler;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private BranchAdapter mAdapter;
private  static MyDatabase db;
private static SQLiteDatabase sdb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recycler= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.maiinRecycler);
    db= new MyDatabase(this);
    sdb= db.getWritableDatabase();
    mLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new BranchAdapter(getApplicationContext(),Branch.getdata());
    recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView search = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class BranchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BranchAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


    private Context context;

    private ArrayList<BranchInformation> branch;

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    String Name;


    public BranchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BranchInformation> branch) {
        this.context = context;
        this.branch = branch;
        // inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_card, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {

        final TextView Title= (TextView)myViewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        final TextView Pledge= (TextView)myViewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.pledgedText);
        final TextView Backers= (TextView)myViewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.backersText);
       // final LinearLayout BranchLayout =(LinearLayout)myViewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.BranchL);
        Title.setText(branch.get(position).Title);
        Pledge.setText("Pleadge: "+branch.get(position).Pledge+" "+branch.get(position).Currency);
        Backers.setText("Backers: "+branch.get(position).Backers);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return branch.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public View view;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view =itemView;
        }


    }
    // This method adds(duplicates) a Object (item ) to our Branch set as well as Recycler View.
}

public static class Branch {

    public static ArrayList<BranchInformation> getdata() {
        ArrayList<BranchInformation> branch = new ArrayList<BranchInformation>();
        // Select All Query
        try {
            String selectQuery = "SELECT title, amtpledged, numbackers, currency FROM data";
            sdb = db.getWritableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = sdb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    BranchInformation current = new BranchInformation();
                    current.Title=cursor.getString(0);
                    current.Pledge= cursor.getString(1);
                    current.Backers= cursor.getString(2);
                    current.Currency= cursor.getString(3);
                    branch.add(current);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            //    Toast.makeText(,"Error Finding data. Please sync to Update Data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        }

        // return contact list
        return branch;
    }
}

public static class BranchInformation {
    public String Title;
    public String Pledge;
    public String Backers;
    public String Currency;


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called pagination.

```
public class BranchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BranchAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


private Context context;

private ArrayList<BranchInformation> branch;

private LayoutInflater inflater;
String Name;


public BranchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<BranchInformation> branch) {
    this.context = context;
    this.branch = branch;
    // inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int position) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.main_card, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int position) {

    final TextView Title= (TextView)myViewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
    final TextView Pledge= (TextView)myViewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.pledgedText);
    final TextView Backers= (TextView)myViewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.backersText);
   // final LinearLayout BranchLayout =(LinearLayout)myViewHolder.view.findViewById(R.id.BranchL);
    Title.setText(branch.get(position).Title);
    Pledge.setText("Pleadge: "+branch.get(position).Pledge+" "+branch.get(position).Currency);
    Backers.setText("Backers: "+branch.get(position).Backers);


}

public void updateList(ArrayList<BranchInformation> list){
   int beforeInsertSize = branch.size();
   branch.addAll(list)
   notifyItemRangeInserted(beforeInsertSize,list.size);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return branch.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public View view;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        view =itemView;
    }


}
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recycler;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private BranchAdapter mAdapter;
private  static MyDatabase db;
private static SQLiteDatabase sdb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   recycler= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.maiinRecycler);
   db= new MyDatabase(this);
   sdb= db.getWritableDatabase();
   mLayoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
   recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
   mAdapter = new 
   BranchAdapter(getApplicationContext(),Branch.getdata());
   recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   recycler.addOnScrollListener(mScrollListener);

}

  RecyclerView.OnScrollListener mScrollListener = new 
  RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) 
   {

        int visibleItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getChildCount();
        int totalItemCount = gridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        int pastVisibleItems = gridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (pastVisibleItems + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
            List< BranchInformation > list = Branch.getData();
            mAdapter.updateList(list);
        }
    }
};
}
```

Your query would be diffrent now

```
int offset; //offset will be the last row number you fetched previously.
```

`//Your query will be something like following.
String selectQuery = "SELECT title, amtpledged, numbackers, currency FROM data LIMIT 20 OFFSET "+offset;`

Comment: Thanks a lot , this really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own logic to load data on demand listening to the scroll events of the `RecyclerView` using `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`.

Or use an open source library, [like this](https://github.com/MarkoMilos/Paginate).